# trying to update xml file but it puts everything in one tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

im trying to update this xml page:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<news>
  <report>
    <user></user>
    <date></date>
    <content></content>
  </report>
</news>
```

with this method:

```
public static void InsetXML(string user, string date, string content, string Xmlfile)
    {


        string XMLfile;
        XmlElement reportEle, userEle, dateEle, contentEle;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XMLfile = Xmlfile;
        doc.Load(XMLfile);
        reportEle = doc.CreateElement("report");
        userEle = doc.CreateElement("user");
        dateEle = doc.CreateElement("date");
        contentEle = doc.CreateElement("content");
        userEle.InnerText = user;
        dateEle.InnerText = date;
        contentEle.InnerText = content;
        reportEle.AppendChild(userEle);
        reportEle.AppendChild(dateEle);
        reportEle.AppendChild(contentEle);
        doc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(reportEle, doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild);
        FileStream fsxml = new FileStream(XMLfile, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        doc.Save(fsxml);
        fsxml.Close();

    }
```

take into consideration, `string Xmlfile =  Server.MapPath("news.xml");`
 (copied the method from a book that i'm using) but every time i try it it just writes everything into the user tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<news>
  <report>
    <user>
    </user>
    <date>
    </date>
    <content>
    </content>
  </report>
  <report>
    <user>dsfdsfg,10.10.1999,sdfas</user>
    <date>
    </date>
    <content>
    </content>
  </report>
</news>
```

thanks to all helpers :D

Comment: Did my solution end up working for you? If so, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.. and I'll leave this [link](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/) for further reference.

```
public static void InsetXML(string user, string date, string content, string Xmlfile)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("news");
    xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

    XmlNode parent = xmlDoc.CreateElement("report");
    rootNode.AppendChild(parent);

    XmlNode child1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("user");
    child1.InnerText = user;
    parent.AppendChild(child1);

    XmlNode child2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("date");
    child2.InnerText = date;
    parent.AppendChild(child2);

    XmlNode child3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("content");
    child3.InnerText = content;
    parent.AppendChild(child3);

    FileStream fsxml = new FileStream(Xmlfile, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    xmlDoc.Save(fsxml);
    fsxml.Close();
}
```

I tested this and wrote the XML to an existing .xml file on my drive.

This was the result:

```
<news>
  <report>
    <user>dsfdsfg</user>
    <date>10.10.1999</date>
    <content>sdfas</content>
  </report>
</news>
```